# How to get updated msql database value to be saved in PHP session?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I established database connection at the very beginning of my code by using PHP. In another JavaScript method, I updated some values in the database and would like to save it in session, but I can't connect to database and get the updated data that I need outside of the first PHP section. I tried to establish another db connection in the middle part of my code, but it doesn't seem to work.

The code is 300+ lines long so I can't show it here, I just need to know how can I query outside of connection class/retain connection throughout the same webpage/update session data whenever a function changes db value.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: show what have you tried...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 'include' or 'require' statement inside your query/php code, for you to call your database connection in every php file you created.

```
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
?>
```

or

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
?>
```